# substituting matrix elements based on condition

Tags: matlab, vector, element

I have the following example (that doesn't work!)

```
a(1, 1:2, 1:2) = [1 2; 3 4];
a(2, 1:2, 1:2) = [5 6; 7 8];

b=a;

for i=1:2
    b(a(i,:,:).*b(i,:,:) < 5.0) = 3*circshift(a(i,:,:), [1 0]);
end
```

So the idea is that all the places where `a(i,:,:).*b(i,:,:)` is less than five, `b(i,:,:)` should get the value of `3*circshift(a, [1 0])` at that place. Is that possible?

I can of course do it with a bunch of `for`-loops, but that doesn't seem like the most optimal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using the following:

```
b( (a.*b)<5 ) = [value you want];
```

Applied to your code:

```
a(1, 1:2, 1:2) = [1 2; 3 4];
a(2, 1:2, 1:2) = [5 6; 7 8];

b=a;

c = 3*circshift( a( (a.*b)<5 ), [1 0]); % first change a

b( (a.*b)<5 ) = c( (a.*b)<5 ); % then store c where (a.*b)<5 in b where (a.*b)<5
```

Notice I use `(a.*b)<5` in `a( (a.*b)<5 )`. A command like `x( condition ) = value;` can be used to tell MATLAB to let `x` be `value` where `condition` is true. This is called logical indexing.

The same effect can be achieved with a for-loop, which can be easier to read for people that know some programming languages, but not MATLAB, but for-loops usually are slower than logical indexing. Another method would be using the `find` function to first find the indices of `b` where the condition `(a.*b)<5` is true, then replacing those indices with the desired value. This too is slower than logical indexing and it needs more code.

Comment: Please see my edit, I meant `a(i,:,:).*b(i,:,:)`, not `b(i,:,:)`... sorry

Comment: @BillyJean - I edited my answer, I hope it answers your question!

Comment: I believe there is an error in the code or you may have misunderstood me. `b` should get the value of `3*circshift(a, [1 0])` *at that place*

Comment: Is the answer better now?